# angularjs partial template with specific scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I'd like to include a partial template inside my main template, but having a specific scope when I call the partial template.

For example, this is my main template (very simplified, actual template is more complicated, so ng-iterate can't be used here) :

```
<h1>title, my item1 name is {{item1.name}}</h1>
....
<div ng-view="myPartial.html" scope="item1"></div>
....
<div ng-view="myPartial.html" scope="item2"></div>
...
```

And myPartial.html is something like

```
<input ng-model="name" />...
```

data :

```
{item1: {name:"test1"}, item2: {name: "test2"}}
```

expected result :

```
<1>title, my item1 name is test1</h1>
....
<div><input value="test1" /></div>
....
<div><input value="test2"></div>
...
```

How would you do this kind of thing using angularjs ?

Should I create a specific directive with myPartial.html as template ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ng-view can only be found once in the page, I used `ng-include` and the `ng-init` to initialize the scope of the specific controller :

```
<div ng-include="'/myPartial.html'" ng-init="init(items.item1)" ng-controller="YourController"></div>
```

controller :

```
this.app.controller("YourController", function YourController($scope) {
    $scope.init = function(item){
        $scope.item = item;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div ng-view="myPartial.html" ng-controller="yourController"></div>`

and then create yourController as angular controller (or use existing) and assign data to `$scope.item1`

Comment: Ok I'll try it, however will the data-binding still work in this case ? I updated my example with a more detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

In case your items are in same format than you will want to use ngInclude. ngView directive is used for different purposes.

Controller:

```
$scope.items = {item1: {name:"test1"}, item2: {name: "test2"}};
```

Main view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-include="'myPartial.html'"></div>
```

myPartial.html:

```
<h2>{{item.name}}</h2>...
```

Comment: My template structure is a bit more complicated as in the example, so I can't use ng-repeat to select my specific item.

Comment: Well, in that case you should update your question to reflect **all** the important side-effects. Otherwise you're disrespecting to the community.

Comment: Yes I just did it, didn't think about ng-repeat before your answer, sry