# AngularJS create partial template with parameter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-templates

I have gone through below [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) questions to get what I want.

[create a single html view for multiple partial views in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12577378/1184435)

[Partial views in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36494842/1184435)

[AngularJs Include Partial Template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22329769/1184435)

[angularjs partial template with specific scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20882122/1184435) - looks close to what I want.

But I believe my case is different from all of them. Hence, the question.

I have got this `HTML` structure which needs to be repeated numerous times.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Enitity1
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="entity1" value="option1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="entity1" value="option2" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="entity1" value="option3" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="entity1" value="option4" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="entity1" value="option5" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to pass the name of the Entity as a parameter and render this HTML template based on the parameter.

I have created a template like below.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        {{entity}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{entity}}" value="option1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{entity}}" value="option2" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{entity}}" value="option3" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{entity}}" value="option4" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{entity}}" value="option5" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

My controller

```
app.controller("entitiesController", ["$scope",
    function entitiesController($scope) {
        $scope.init = function init(entity) {
            $scope.entity= entity;
        };
    }
]);
```

And I am trying to render the same for multiple entities as below inside a `<tbody>` element.

```
<ng-include src="Common/entities.html" ng-controller="entitiesController" ng-init="init('Entity1')"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="Common/entities.html" ng-controller="entitiesController" ng-init="init('Entity2')"></ng-include>
<!-- Some more entities here...-->
```

But it does not work. It does not throw any error as well in the console.

How do I go about this? What is the proper way of handling this? Is it possible to handle it with a template or should I just put HTML for all the entities manually?

Comment: can you not create a directive for this need?

Comment: @tanmay Well, I am relatively new to AngularJS. Can you please provide a brief idea how a directive can work in this situation?

Comment: I mean I have created some basic directives recently, but not to emit or insert any HTML template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a `directive` to do this for you. Something like,

```
myApp.directive("myEntity", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      entity: "="
    },
    templateUrl: "Common/entities.html"
  }
})
```

Now, you can use the template you already created in `Common/entities.html` which is,

```
<tr>
    <td>
        {{entity}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{entity}}" value="option1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{entity}}" value="option2" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{entity}}" value="option3" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{entity}}" value="option4" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="{{entity}}" value="option5" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Finally, use it like `<my-entity entity="entityObj"></my-entity>` where `entityObj` is a variable in your `$scope` (or accordingly if you use `controllerAs` syntax)

**EDIT**: Other way is to have the directive as attribute and not element.

```
myApp.directive("myEntity", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    ...
  }
})
```

And, remove the `<tr>` from the template. Now, we can use it like,

```
<tbody>
  <tr my-entity entity="entityObj">
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Strange, it's working. However, it only emits the part where there are expressions in the template. That too not inside its parent element but somewhere else. Any ideas?

Comment: It only gets the `input` elements, not the `<td>`s. Also, I am putting this directive inside a `<tbody>` tag, like `<tbody><my-entities entity="entityObj"></my-entity></tbody>`. But it is rendered somewhere else on my page not in the `<tbody>` element.

Comment: Yeah, the rendering issue is gone now. It is rendering where it is supposed to. But it is not setting the values in the `{{}}` expressions. I am using it like this: `<tr my-entity entity="Entity1"></tr>`. But it does not replace the value in the expression with the parameter `Entity1`, it is replacing it with a blank.

Comment: Maybe because I am passing it as a text variable, not as a `scope` object. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi yes, as I mentioned, you need to have `entityObj` as a variable in `$scope`. Though there is another way, you can have `entity: "@"` instead of `"="` in the directive definition.. and then pass it like `<tr my-entity entity="'Entity1'"></tr>`. Notice the single quotes inside as well

Comment: I didn't need the single quotes though, only the `@` instead of `=` did the trick. Putting it in the single quote was rendering it with the single quote.

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi oh yeah, mistook visualizing it, glad it is working at last :)

Comment: Yeah, your patience and time paid off to help me. Thank you so very much. Learned a great deal only from your answer and comments. Such as what restrict="A" and "E" are for. What "=" and "@" are for.

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi no prob, glad it helped!